# PHP sessions using cross domain form processor

Tags: php

I have a download page on my site. In order to reach it you have to fill out a form, unfortunately due to legacy coding beyond my control the form is processed via a script on another domain (where our crm lives).

I am having trouble passing the session value that is added when you successfully submit the form to the download page. Again, the user fills out a form, form is processed and the session value added and they should be returned to the download page.

The download page should be inacessible in any other situation. Don't want people bypassing the form and going straight to the download.

processor script code

```
<?PHP
  session_start();
  //lots of database stuff

  //successful insertion to database
  if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
    {
        $redirect .= '?sessionid=xvyXXXXX';
        header("Location: http://" . $redirect);
    }
?>
```

software download page code

```
<?php
$code = $_GET['sessionid'];

if(strcmp( $code , 'xvyXXXXX'  ) != 0) {
    header("Location: http://kinetick.com/V3/download-registration.php");
} else {
       header("Location: http://kinetick.com/V3/download-software.php");
}
?>
```

I can't get this to work. Is there another way taking into account the processor script is on another domain? currently when I remove the if/else and put a print its showing an empty array. Need some help big time! thx all

Comment: You said the session value is added (to the link I assume) when the user successfully fills out the form.  Are you 100% sure the session value is being added to the link correctly (spelled correctly)?  It should look something like this  `http://website.com/Some_Page.php?Session_Value=1`

Comment: I wasn't hard coding the session value into the link, was trying to avoid that, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: http://" . $redirect);

this line will eventually look like this...

http://?sessionid=1234xxx

missing something?

yes

should be http://domain.com/somepage.php?sessionid=1234xxx

...
I would rather check out the `curl` library as this will hide the session id and user would never know what session id was passed to that website unless they have read this post :)

Comment: @Val - so add the session ID into the url. damn, should have known that. No worries, its not the real session, im dumb but not that dumb! thx!

Comment: not sure I follow, $redirect is defined as $redirect = ("http://www.domain.com/page.php");

Comment: `$redirect .= '?sessionid=xvyXXXXX';` add `die($redirect);` just after it and then let me know what it prints out. because unless you had a `$redirect = 'domain.com/page.php';` at an earlier page i presume your code would out put. `http://?sessionid=xxx`

Comment: if (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)))
  {
   $redirect .= '?sessionid=xvy1234dds2';
   header("Location: http://" . $redirect);
   die($redirect);
  }
to the processor, it now allows you to hit the page and prints NULL

Comment: you have to put die(); before your header(); otherwise you have been redirected and the die function is not effective.